# Fastest way to convert big raster to polyline using R or Python?

Tags: python, r, performance

I have a big raster file (129600 by 64800 pixel) with global water bodies (1 bit values 0 and 1) and try to extract ocean and inland water shorelines.

I've tried with ArcGIS and QGIS to convert from raster to polyline, but it takes ages.

Does anybody know a better/faster way (Python or R) or a better tool for this task?

**Update**

- R: rasterToContour might be fast and precise but if you have a very large dataset like mine (8,398,080,000 pixels) you need either a very big amount of RAM (more than 16GB) or you force R to do more processing on the hard drive and it will also take ages.
- Python/GDAL: gdal_poligonize creates polygons instead of polylines

**Update 2**

- R rasterToContour: rasterToContour does not deliver the wanted results. Compared to ArcGIS (raster to polygon followed by feature to line) it does not extract the exact pixel outline, as shown in the examples below.

rasterToContour result
[image: rasterToContour result]

ArcGIS result
[image: ArcGIS result]

**UPDATE 3**

Python/GDAL: I've run gdal_polygonize from command line against ArcGIS on a test dataset and the results were extremely clear:

- gdal: 49 seconds
- ArcGIS: 1.84 seconds

Comment: Did that, see Update 3.

Comment: Can you provide that test dataset, so we can see if proposed alternatives are faster and/or produce the required results?

Comment: For such a huge raster, you'd be way better using C/C++ with gdal library.

Answer (score 12):

Edit: In the latest version of `sf` (v0.9.1) and `stars` (v0.4.1), you need to specify the `merge = TRUE` argument in the call to `sf::st_as_stars()` function.

For posterity, I've been having success with the `stars::` package in `R` for doing this type of operation quickly.

```
library(raster)
library(stars)
library(sf)
library(magrittr)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
r[r[] < 750] <- 0
r[r[] >= 750] <- 1

x <- st_as_stars(r) %>% 
  st_as_sf(merge = TRUE) %>% # this is the raster to polygons part
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") # cast the polygons to polylines

plot(x)
```

[image]

```
plot(r)
plot(x, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I'm working with R and used `rasterToPolygons` from the `raster` package in the past, but now I prefer `gdal_polygonizeR` by John Baumgartner. It bases on  `gdal_polygonize.py` and is much faster.
John Baumgartner published the code and gave an example for usage in his [blog](https://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/getting-rasters-into-shape-from-r/).

If you are familiar with python you could use `gdal_polygonize.py` directly of course.

Comment: I'll give it I try. Last time I've used gdal_polygonize.py ArcGIS was still faster.

Comment: I didn't expect that ArcGis can be faster that gdal. @Generic Militzer

Comment: Ah wait, this will create polygons but I need polylines.

Comment: If you put your data into a File Geodatabase it is pretty fast. But still not fast enough. That's why I'm searching for alternatives.

Comment: It's not necessarily a problem that you get polygons, you can always convert them to polylines (although, with that many it could of course take a while as well).

Answer (score 4):

Try `rasterToContour` from the **raster** package.

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
r[r[] < 750] <- 0
r[r[] >= 750] <- 1

x <- rasterToContour(r)
class(x)
> [1] "SpatialLinesDataFrame"
> attr(,"package")
> [1] "sp"

plot(r)
plot(x, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

You may then easily write the files to a local folder, e.g. as 'ESRI Shapefile' (.shp), using the below code. Have a look at `ogrDrivers` from **rgdal** to find out which drivers your system is compatible with.

```
library(rgdal)
writeOGR(x, dsn = getwd(), layer = "coastlines", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: I'll try and keep fingers crossed it will not kill my RAM. Even though I have 16GB, which hopefully is enough, R sometimes is not so efficient with big raster files. But let's see.

Comment: Conversion worked somehow, but I wasn't able to check in detail. As I am usually more into raster data processing, can you tell me how I can transfer the SpatialLineDataFrame into a shapefile or something comparable. I've googled and still struggling, as I don't know the layer name (OGRwrite).

Comment: Haha, I definitely see your point. See above update.

Comment: Ah, stupid me. the layer variable is something I can define...I didn't get that.

Comment: Another hint: try to set 'maxpixels' in `rasterToContour` to some higher value, e.g. 1e+9. You'll end up with more details then. The default setting creates quite generalized contour lines.

Comment: To get a pixel wise contour do I have to use the number of pixels of the input image? This would be 8,398,080,000 which is quite a lot. Using 1,000,000,000 nearly crashed my PC and I had to stop the process.

Comment: If you're not willing to `resample` your data to a coarser spatial resolution, the only solution I can imagine then would be to split your data into multiple tiles (e.g. 16 sub-rasters), then perform `rasterToContour` on each tile separately in an iterative manner and, finally, `merge` the resulting shapefiles into one huge shapefile. In case you are interested, our working group's package [**Rsenal**](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal) offers a function called `splitRaster` to create multiple sub-rasters from one huge raster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30344/discussion-between-generic-militzer-and-fdetsch).

Answer (score 2):

While I'm a big fan of GDAL, the polygonize tool was way too slow for my applications as well.

A fast alternative is `gdal_trace_outline` from [**Dans GDAL scripts**](https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts) which also has more options regarding tolerance, donuts, etc.

Like `gdal_polygonize` this also produces polygons which you'd need to convert afterwards with `ogr2ogr -nlt MULTILINESTRING`.

Downside to that is you need to compile it yourself, unless you are on a Linux or Mac OsX System.

Comment: Unfortunately it failed with the error message: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I am guessing my file is too big or more precise it will produce too many small polygons.