# GDAL error in R path.expand(path): invalid 'path' argument

Tags: gdal, r, installation

Using windows 10.

I would like to stick to using R since that's where a lot of my pre-processing and analysis will take place for a bigger project.

I have downloaded a number of MODIS files for the MOD13A3 product, they are in hdf format. The end goal is to create a loop to convert the hdf files into a tiff, scale, clip and project the NDVI and EVI layers.

I am getting stuck before I even attempt those steps with this strange error when I try to use some of the gdalUtils functions:

```
Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument
```

I get this when trying:

```
gdalinfo("C:\\Users\\mydirectory\\R\\MOD13A3.A2015335.h13v03.005.2016007192527.hdf")
```

I have also tried using different types of paths like:

```
gdalinfo("MOD13A3.A2015335.h13v03.005.2016007192527.hdf")
```

I even get this error when trying: `gdal_setInstallation()` and `get_subdatasets`

Additionally, `gdal-config` produces an error. I suspect this is due to a weird installation issue and environment path if someone could provide a bit of guidance!

I have my working directory set to the same folder where these files are found.

I haven't been able to find much on this error so I'm hoping somebody here can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have resolved one issue, but another still persists so I will ask in another question.

I think there were conflicts with 32-bit and 64-bit installs. Since ArcGIS runs python in 32-bit and I am on a 64-bit machine, initially, I assumed I would install the 64-bit builds for GDAL. When I installed the 32-bit versions and their python binaries, changed the environment paths,  I was able to then use the commands in R. I followed this decent guide here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/installing-gdal-python-windows-kosal-khun

Unfortunately I am still having an issue using the commands with the .hdf files but I suspect that may be another issue as the commands work with a .tif I tested.

Comment: Avoid answering like this. Please include these extra steps you have taken in your original post since the problem still persists.

Comment: @FaridCher different question since the errors are different and I would have had to delete the entire post and change the title. GDAL is now working but producing a different error.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199647/hdf-files-in-gdal-throwing-an-error-in-r-gdalinfo

Answer (score 0):

An important caveat that you omit is, what OS are your using? The function may be parsing the path in a specific way. Have you tried your path without double separators?

```
gdalUtils::gdalinfo("C:/Users/mydirectory/R/MOD13A3.A2015335.h13v03.005.2016007192527.hdf")
```

You should also make sure that you are running the most current version of R and gdalUtils. You can run "Update packages..." from the "Packages" menu. If you are running R through RStudio, in a word, don't. It does not behave well with the spatial classes.

Comment: Updated question, using windows 10. Tried your method without the double separators and got: `Warning message: running command '"C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\bin\gdalinfo.exe" "C:/directory" had status 1`

Comment: I'm wondering if my qgis install is messing up some sort of reference gdal?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to this question:

[How to speed up raster to polygon conversion in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192771/how-to-speed-up-raster-to-polygon-conversion-in-r)

In there, I have briefly described how to install Gdal on windows. If you had extra questions feel free to comment here.