# GDAL framework does not exists after brew install; cannot locate gdal_polygonize.py

Tags: raster, gdal, r

I am trying to get raster to shape form in R using [John Baumgartner's](https://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/getting-rasters-into-shape-from-r/) code.  This function needs gdal_polygonize.py from gdal package. I installed gdal package using: (I am using MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.6)

```
brew install gdal --HEAD
```

When I check for the version. It seems I have installed GDAL:

```
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.3.0dev, released 2017/99/99
```

Now when I try to run the gdal_polygoniseR function. It gives error. It needs gdal_polygonize.py file. I am stuck at this point:

```
> system.time(p <- gdal_polygonizeR(r1))
Error in gdal_polygonizeR(r1) : 
Can't find gdal_polygonize.py on your system.
```

I wanted to check if it exists or not and if it does then its path:

```
> Sys.which("gdal_polygonize.py")
gdal_polygonize.py 
            ""
```

I saw that there is one additional [step](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192771/how-to-speed-up-raster-to-polygon-conversion-in-r/195251) after installing [GDAL](http://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/gdal/):

```
echo 'export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I am able to run this line but does not help as the framework folder does not have gdal folder. When I check for this I do not see "GDAL.framework" in my "Library/Frameworks/..".

If I am able to locate the ".py" file. I will be able to run the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the unix paths in Mac OS X (see [GDAL: Building On Mac](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnMac))

1) The GDAL pre-compiled binaries of [Kyng Chaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#gdal_complete) use the Framework way (installed in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework`).

Control

```
 $ /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/unix/bin/gdal-config --libs
-L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/unix/lib -lgdal
 $ /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/unix/bin/gdal-config --cflags
-I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Headers2
```

2) The Homebrew way installs all in `/usr/local/Cellar/` with symbolic links  in `/usr/local/bin/`

Control

```
$ gdal-config --libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gdal2/2.2/lib -lgdal
$ gdal-config --cflags
-I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal2/2.2/include
```

So, if you have installed only the Homebrew version, it is normal that

> I do not see "GDAL.framework" in my "Library/Frameworks/..".

And there's no need to add `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs` to your PATH

3) Now to find the gdal_polygonize.py  file, simply use in the terminal

```
locate gdal_polygonize.py
```

Comment: This is helpful. Though `locate` command does not work for Mac OS. `mdfind gdal_polygonize.py` did the job for me. The function gives me another error `from osgeo import gdal ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo' Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : Cannot open data source`. I hope to find some solution for this as well.