# Error while converting raster to ploygon using stars package

Tags: raster, r, polygonize, stars

I am trying to convert raster to polygon using `stars` package as suggested in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192771/how-to-speed-up-raster-to-polygon-conversion-in-r) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166753/fastest-way-to-convert-big-raster-to-polyline-using-r-or-python/313550). I have used the following code

```
library(raster)
library(stars)
library(sf)
library(magrittr)

#read raster
r1<-raster("raster_name.asc")

# convert raster to polygon, dissolved neighboring same values
r.to.poly<-st_as_stars(r1) %>% 
  st_as_sf(merge = TRUE)
```

which is giving me the following error

> Error in CPL_polygonize(file, mask_name, "GTiff", "Memory", "foo", options,  :
> basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue a few days ago. What seemed to work for me was adding a projection before doing the conversion. I also noticed that using a SpatialGridDataFrame (instead of a RasterLayer) object worked much faster. So I suggest you try something like this (assuming you use the WGS84 CRS)

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(stars)
library(dplyr)

readGDAL("raster_name.asc", p4s = '+init=EPSG:4326') %>%
st_as_stars() %>%
st_as_sf(as_points = FALSE, merge = TRUE)
```